# How to do different login by roles ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

After a little research and with the help of another fellow from here, i managed to create an "Admin" role and assign it to an user ( I only needed one Admin ). Now i have some troubles with making the login redirect to different pages regarding the role the user has.
I am using asp.net core 2.2 default web site template and authentication selected as individual user account. 
Here is my CreateRole method:

```
private async Task CreateUserRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

    IdentityResult roleResult;
    //Adding Admin Role
    var roleCheck = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
    if (!roleCheck)
    {
        //create the roles and seed them to the database
        roleResult = await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
    }
    //Assign Admin role to the main User here we have given our newly registered 
    //login id for Admin management
    ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("example@gmail.com");
    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
}
```

And here is the post of my Login method with what i've tried so far:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        var status = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin");
        if (Input.Email.Contains(status.ToString()))
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }                
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: You may not want to post an email address online. You should anonymize the one in your code sample.

Comment: You are right, didn't even notice that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the user's role from the database:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
// Get the roles for the user
var roles = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

if (roles.Any(role=>"Admin".Equals(role)))
{
    return LocalRedirect("YourURL");
}
```

Or use `UserManager.IsInRoleAsync` function :

```
var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

var isInRole = await _signInManager.UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
if (isInRole)
{
    return LocalRedirect("YourURL");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right after the user logged in you can check their role using `HttpContext.User.IsInRole` function:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    var principal = await _signInManager.ClaimsFactory.CreateAsync(user);
    if (principal.IsInRole("Admin")) {
        return LocalRedirect("SomeSpecialUrlForAdmin");
    }
    else {
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work...it looks like `HttpContext.User` doesn't acctually come with my user.

Comment: Hm. Do you mean `HttpContext.User` returns `null`? Or something else?

Comment: Yes. It seems `HttpContext.User` is not filled automatically with all necessary claims right after login. So, you need to get your own `principal` and call its `IsInRole` method instead. 
I'll update the code above in a minute.